# Multiply a layer by a boolean mask in Keras, getting error 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Plenty of threads on this error, but I can't seem to apply them to my case.  Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to do:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, multiply, Dense, Lambda, Multiply
import keras.backend as K
```

Some dummy data:

```
xx = np.array([1,2,3]).reshape(3,1)
maskvec = np.array([1,2,3]).reshape(3,1)
```

This is a function to compare a mask to a value in the mask:

```
def compfun(x):
    comp = K.equal(x[0], x[1])
    return K.cast(comp, dtype = "float32")


inp = Input(shape = (1,))
lay = Dense(1)(inp)
mask = Input(shape = (1,))
m2 = Lambda(compfun)([mask, K.variable(2)]) #2 is a magic number.  In my use-case it'll be in a for-loop
masked = multiply([lay, m2])
model = Model(inputs = [inp, mask], outputs = [masked])
```

And the dreaded

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'
```

Would really appreciate some insight into what's going on here!  Really banging my head against the wall.

I've tried making the second argument to `compfun` into an array rather than a constant, but I get the same error (I have no idea if `K.equal` can take scalars or not when another argument is a vector)

Answer (score 1):

You can change it like this:

```
def compfun(x):
    comp = K.equal(x, K.variable(2))
    return K.cast(comp, dtype = "float32")


m2 = Lambda(compfun)(mask)
```

Comment: Which is to say that the problem, as I've also discovered, is that these Lambdas can't take two arguments.  I've also figured it out, and should have deleted the question.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem was that `Lambdas choke when you give  them an argument that is a list, because they don't know what to do with the non-layer part of the function.  I handled the problem like this:

```
for i in np.unique(loc_idx): 
    mask = Lambda(lambda x: K.cast(K.equal(x, i), dtype = "float32"))(loc_inp)
```